# Navigating explorer.exe through command line

Tags: windows, windows-7, command-prompt

I am trying to write a program which can make navigation to a particular file easier.

I am using windows 7, if I write the command

```
explorer.exe c:
```

in the command prompt it opens c drive, but suppose I want to open a folder 'NewFolder' and if I write

```
explorer.exe c:\newfolder
```

a entirely new window is created showing the directory. I want to reach the destination without creating new windows and its necessary to be done in steps, that is first opening c drive then NewFolder. Is it possible to navigate in the same window through command prompt..?

Can I access Address bar from the prompt..?

Also can we access 'back' button from the command line...?

thanks in advance.

Comment: This one is for http://superuser.com/ I guess

Comment: you may see this for explorer options http://support.microsoft.com/KB/152457

Comment: I might be wrong but the link you mentioned does not have information on how to achieve what I have asked..can you please help a bit more..